# android processing bar problem

Tags: android, processing

My programme retrieves some data from server. Usually it takes few seconds. I want to generate a processing bar for this. And I know how to generate it. But how to distinguish and control when close processing bar.
My programme:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
        but1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
        but2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send2);
        edit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);

        but1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Socket socket=null;
                String mesg=edit1.getText().toString()+"\r\n";
            try {
                socket=new Socket("localhost",30000);
                //send information to server
                PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
                out.println(mesg);
                //receive information from server
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String mstr=br.readLine();
            if(mstr!=null)
            {
                text1.setText(mstr);
            }else
            {
                text1.setText("error");
            }
                out.close();
                br.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG,e.toString());
            }
            }        
        });
      }
```

This a client program. The amount of data is really huge. So how can I do the processing bar. How can I CONTROL it?
Thank!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Progress Dialog for this.

Here is this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
      text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textin);
     but1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
     but2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send2);
     edit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
      but1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
     {
         public void onClick(View v) {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Places.this,
            "Please wait...", "Connecting...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                }});

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

             Socket socket=null;
             String mesg=edit1.getText().toString()+"\r\n";
         try {
             socket=new Socket("localhost",30000);
             //send information to server
             PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
             out.println(mesg);
             //receive information from server
             BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
             String mstr=br.readLine();
         if(mstr!=null)
         {
             text1.setText(mstr);
         }else
         { 
            text1.setText("error");
         }
             out.close();
             br.close();
             socket.close();
             sleep(3000);

         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }catch(Exception e)
         {
             Log.e(DEBUG_TAG,e.toString());
         }
         mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }                   

    }.start();
   } 
   }); 
                  }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask

Here is an awsome tutorial on progress bars.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to tell user that downloading has been completed, then you can use Toast. Throw the message "Downloading" just before downloading starts and disable Toast message on download completion.

Suppose you want to show the % of completed download, then you should implement your own progress bar (Similar to seek bar in Media Player). Keep on updating progress bar based on % completed (say per second basis).

Shash